# In react, how to display component only after all data is available?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I have a component that displays images. The component has a menu bar as well.

During initially server request, this component always shows the menu bar for a split second because the actually image is not loaded yet.

How to display the menu bar only after the image is ready?

EDITED:

I can determine when the URLs to the images are loaded and available. But how to tell if the actually image itself is ready?

Comment: If you share some code, I can answer more accurately, but let's say you have a state called images where you store your images after getting them from api. before your main return statement, you can use an if and return a loading indicator if images are not loaded.

Comment: Please add more to the question whether the image source is local disk or something else, sharing a code snippet would be actually helpful, making a wild guess I feel You need to implement conditional rendering of the component only if the image is available in case if you are getting it from remote source. from local disk sometimes it takes few milliseconds depending on the size of the image format.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
function YourComponent () {
    
    const [imgLoaded, setImgLoaded] = useState(false);
   
    const handleImgLoad = () => {
        setImgLoaded(true);
    }

    return(
        <>
            <img onLoad={handleImgLoad} src="..." alt="..." />
            {imgLoaded ? <MenuBar /> : <></>}
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use partial rendering
for example

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

    function App() {
    
    
      const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    
      useEffect(()=>{
        setData(true);
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div>
          {data && <div> after data is not null this will be visible</div>}
        </div>
      );
    }
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a loading state set to true by default, this way:

```js
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
```

After you have all your data fetched, you set it to false:

```js
setLoading(false)
```

And your render will be something like this:

```js
return (
  <div>
    {loading ? <p>loading...</p> : <MyComponent/>}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a state as below and load the menu based on this value;

```
const [ImageLoaded, setImageLoaded] = useState(false);
```